# JAVAX JSR 356 Websocket with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket

I am trying to implement a server side websocket endpoint using the Javax JSR 356 API in a Spring Boot project. I am following [this](https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/23/spring-framework-4-0-m1-websocket-support) tutorial. I know there are a few questions asked on SO on this topic but I was not able to find a plausible solution. When I try to connect to the websocket using a client (ARC) it just reports "unknown error occurred". I checked the logs of the embedded Tomcat server but there are no any entries. According to the Tomcat startup entries, the context path of the application is empty (""), so I am sure I accessing the websocket with the correct URI.

This is my code:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/socket", configurator = SpringConfigurator.class)
public class WebSocketController
{
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Socket has been opened: " + session.getId());
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) throws IonException
    {
        System.out.println("Socket has been closed: " + session.getId());
    }
}

Spring configuration class
@Configuration
public class WebSocketConfig
{
    @Bean
    public WebSocketController webSocketController()
    {
        return new WebSocketController();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletContextAware endpointExporterInitializer(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        return new ServletContextAware() {

            @Override
            public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
                ServerEndpointExporter serverEndpointExporter = new ServerEndpointExporter();
                serverEndpointExporter.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
                try {
                    serverEndpointExporter.afterPropertiesSet();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

How can I go about implementing a server side websocket endpoint in a Spring Boot application?

Update:
After following the first answer, log of Tomcat server. It stops as soon as it starts.

```
2018-08-16 00:16:37.160  INFO 12944 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.s.s.ServerEndpointExporter       : Registering @ServerEndpoint class: class io.ai.vivid.zen.controller.WebSocketController
2018-08-16 00:16:37.169  INFO 12944 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-08-16 00:16:37.170 DEBUG 12944 --- [cat-startStop-1] o.apache.catalina.mapper.MapperListener  : Unregister host [localhost] at domain [null] for service [StandardService[Tomcat]]
2018-08-16 00:16:37.170 DEBUG 12944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.apache.catalina.mapper.MapperListener  : Unregister Context [] for service [StandardService[Tomcat]]
2018-08-16 00:16:37.170 DEBUG 12944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.apache.catalina.mapper.MapperListener  : Unregister Wrapper [default] in Context [] for service [StandardService[Tomcat]]
2018-08-16 00:16:37.170 DEBUG 12944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.apache.catalina.mapper.MapperListener  : Unregister Wrapper [dispatcherServlet] in Context [] for service [StandardService[Tomcat]]
2018-08-16 00:16:37.170 DEBUG 12944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Stopping filters
2018-08-16 00:16:37.170 DEBUG 12944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       :  Stopping filter 'requestContextFilter'
2018-08-16 00:16:37.171 DEBUG 12944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.core.ApplicationFilterConfig       : JMX de-registration complete for filter of type [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedRequestContextFilter] and name [requestContextFilter]
2018-08-16 00:16:37.171 DEBUG 12944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       :  Stopping filter 'Tomcat WebSocket (JSR356) Filter'
2018-08-16 00:16:37.171 DEBUG 12944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.core.ApplicationFilterConfig       : JMX de-registration complete for filter of type [org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter] and name [Tomcat WebSocket (JSR356) Filter]
2018-08-16 00:16:37.171 DEBUG 12944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       :  Stopping filter 'httpPutFormContentFilter'
2018-08-16 00:16:37.171 DEBUG 12944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.core.ApplicationFilterConfig       : JMX de-registration complete for filter of type [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter] and name [httpPutFormContentFilter]
2018-08-16 00:16:37.171 DEBUG 12944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       :  Stopping filter 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter'
2018-08-16 00:16:37.171 DEBUG 12944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.core.ApplicationFilterConfig       : JMX de-registration complete for filter of type [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedHiddenHttpMethodFilter] and name [hiddenHttpMethodFilter]
2018-08-16 00:16:37.171 DEBUG 12944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       :  Stopping filter 'characterEncodingFilter'
2018-08-16 00:16:37.171 DEBUG 12944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.core.ApplicationFilterConfig       : JMX de-registration complete for filter of type [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter] and name [characterEncodingFilter]
2018-08-16 00:16:37.171 DEBUG 12944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.session.StandardManager     : Stopping
2018-08-16 00:16:37.171 DEBUG 12944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.session.StandardManager     : Unloading persisted sessions
2018-08-16 00:16:37.171 DEBUG 12944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.session.StandardManager     : No persisted sessions to unload
2018-08-16 00:16:37.171 DEBUG 12944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : Sending application stop events
2018-08-16 00:16:37.172 DEBUG 12944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : Processing standard container shutdown
2018-08-16 00:16:37.172 DEBUG 12944 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader  : Stopping this Loader
2018-08-16 00:16:37.172 DEBUG 12944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : getResourceAsStream(org/apache/catalina/loader/JdbcLeakPrevention.class)
2018-08-16 00:16:37.172 DEBUG 12944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :   Delegating to parent classloader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@28c97a5
2018-08-16 00:16:37.175 DEBUG 12944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :   --> Returning stream from parent
2018-08-16 00:16:37.183 DEBUG 12944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : resetContext Tomcat:j2eeType=WebModule,name=//localhost/,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none
2018-08-16 00:16:37.183 DEBUG 12944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : Stopping complete
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Websocket Configuration works like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfiguration implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        //registry.addHandler(unitWebSocketHandler, "/unit").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketController webSocketController() {
        return new WebSocketController();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServerEndpointExporter serverEndpointExporter() {
        return new ServerEndpointExporter();
    }
}
```

And then remove configurator = SpringConfigurator.class

So your endpoint just looks like this:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/socket")
public class WebSocketController
```

The example project is available on GitHub:
https://github.com/simasch/spring-boot-websocket

Comment: Because `WebSocketHandlerRegistry` is not used to add handler in my code, the Tomcat server stops right after it starts. What should be specified in the registerWebSocketHandlers method?

Comment: As I said for me this works. Do you see any exception?

Comment: There are no exceptions. I have posted the log output of the Tomcat server. Please have a look.

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: Spring Boot version 2.0.4.RELEASE

Comment: I created a little test project and everything works fine. Check it out: https://github.com/simasch/spring-boot-websocket

Comment: Thank you very much for taking you time to do this. I will check and report back. Cheers!

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, if a websockt server class contains path variable like ```@ServerEndpoint(value = "/{userID}/"```, th spring boot app doesn't start with the errror: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The path [/{userID}/] contains one or more empty segments which are is not permitted". Do you know how to handle this cituation?